# Change keyboard layout without restarting system that applies to all virtual terminal instances

Tags: debian, terminal, keyboard-layout

The devices I work with and develop on are made by a Danish company. Whenever we ssh into into the Debian 8 based devices, they keyboard layout is US QWERTY, but if we attach a US USB keyboard to the device itself, they keyboard layout is Danish.

I've been trying to find a simple way to set the keyboard layout across all 10 virtual terminals, as we use them for development purposes. (They are a mingetty run by a systemd service on boot).

*I've found that I can somewhat successfully change the layout to US if I:*

- Am SSH'd into the device
- Edit `/etc/default/keyboard` manually to have `XKBLAYOUT="us"` instead of `XKBLAYOUT="dk"`
- Run `udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change`

However, it didn't change the layout for Virtual Terminals that I then log into locally afterward.

*I can successfully change the layout to US for all VTs if I:*

- Am SSH'd into the device or am logged in locally
- Edit `/etc/default/keyboard` manually to have `XKBLAYOUT="us"` instead of `XKBLAYOUT="dk"`
- Reboot the device

**Is there any other way to get these changes to stick without having to restart the whole device?**

I know that all I need to do is change the `XKBLAYOUT` so when I've tried using `setxkbmap -model pc105 -layout us` I get back `Cannot open display "default display"` back. *Note: When I ssh or locally login to the device I am root, and have been running all commands as root.*

My `/etc/default/keyboard` file is very simple:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="dk"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

My goal is to script the process so all QA has to do is run a simple script to change back and fourth between US (So they can type more easily) and Danish (So they can set the device back to be as similar to production devices as possible).

Comment: Did you "consult the keyboard(5) manual page"? It says: "In order to activate the changes on the console, run setupcon(1)."

Comment: I had seen it but didn't think to use it because we do run some apps via X and according to [this site](https://benohead.com/debian-change-the-keyboard-layout-from-the-console/) it said that you need to run `udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change` to apply the change for X. I thought it wouldn't work for me, but it does. (at least for all the non X terminals).

Comment: Are you running X applications remotely, or are you running them on an X server on the device itself?

Comment: @StephenKitt The X server is running locally on the device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Debian, to set up the keyboard (and font) on VTs not running X, you should run [`setupcon`](https://manpages.debian.org/setupcon.1). To reconfigure the default keyboard, and set it up, you should run `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`.

`setupcon` can use multiple variants of its configuration files, which would allow you to quickly switch between keyboard layouts.

The system’s keyboard configuration has no impact on the mappings used over SSH: SSH doesn’t transmit keystrokes, it transmits characters, there is no keyboard-style mapping involved.